# "SQL command not properly ended" by creating a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE seq_mitarbeiterid
    INCREMENT BY 1
    START WITH 0
    MAX VALUE 9999
    NOCACHE
    NOCYCLE;
```

I can't see what's wrong with that statement or why I get that error message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look to me that `CREATE SEQUENCE` is a command that works in almost any database engine **other than the one you tagged**

Comment: So what database are you actually using?

Comment: @asparagus . . . As far as I know, MySQL does not support sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it looks like you are using Oracle. If so, there is a syntax error near `MAX VALUE` - which should be `MAXVALUE`.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_mitarbeiterid
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 0
MAXVALUE 9999    -- Here
NOCACHE
NOCYCLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, MySQL does not support sequences.  These are usually used to provide incremental ids for tables.  If that is your purpose, then use `auto_increment`:

```
create table t (
    t_id int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);
```